# shell/linux scripting only selecting certain files to FTP

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ftp

A list of csv files in directory need to be validated. Each column should pass its own validation; thus $1 is first coulmn and it shouldn't be null and so on...

After the csv file passed each validation for each column, it is considered a good file. Now how do I do go about extracting these good files so I can ftp them to another location?

1. Should I just ftp each file after each validation? (Too much time?)
2. Create a list of names of the good files and pass it into an array so i can iterate through the array later to pass it to ftp?

Here is my attempt so far.

```
#!/bin/sh

for file in /source/*.csv

do
   awk -F',' '{
$date_regex = '~(0[1-9]|1[012])[- /.](0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- /.](19|20)\d\d~';

 if (length($1) == "")  
break
 if (length($2) == "") && (length($2) > 30)
break
 if (length($3) == "") && ($3 !~ /$date_regex/)
break
 if (length($4) == "") && (($4 != "S") || ($4 != "E")   
break
 if (length($5) == "") && ((length($5) < 9 || (length($5) > 11)))
break

}' file

    #whatever you need with "$file"
done
```

Comment: I think either way 1 or 2 is OK. you don't know how to implement it or you want to know which way is better?

Comment: i dont know how to implement it, i am new to shell scripting, any insight would be appreciated

Comment: The validation script is not functional, working Awk code, either.  Maybe decide if you need help with that part first, or if you want help with the FTP part, in which case maybe replace the Awk script with an even simpler but working placeholder script.

Comment: you can replace your `break` with `exit 1` in awk. Then in the for loop: do `if awk ... [file name]; then ftp ... $file; fi`

Comment: @qqibrow would you expand your answer i wasn't able to follow\

Answer (score 0):

Exit 1 from awk if check fails. Use if statement to transfer file when awk succeed.

```
#!/bin/sh

    for file in /source/*.csv; do
       if awk -F',' '{
     # your multiple checks here.
     if (length($1) == "") && (length($2) == "") && (length($2) > 30) && ...)
           exit 1
    }' "$file"; then [scp or ftp command as you like]; fi       
    done
```

Comment: how would i refer to the file that was just in the iteration. Say the first file is good file, and now i want to use it to ftp how i specify/reference it

Comment: "$file" is the variable represent the file name.  try `for file in /source/*.csv; do echo "$file"; done` and you will get it.